# AWS Lambda: How to pass more than one parameter to a method?

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a very simple AWS Lambda Method as below

```
public class App 
{
    public App(){}
    
    public void truckTracker(String lang, String lon)
    {
        System.out.println("Lat: "+lang+ " Long: "+lon);
    }

    
}
```

Here is my **template.yaml**

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: >
  secondlambda

  Sample SAM Template for secondlambda

# More info about Globals: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/docs/globals.rst
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 20

Resources:
  HelloWorldFunction:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function # More info about Function Resource: https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md#awsserverlessfunction
    Properties:
      CodeUri: HelloWorldFunction
      Handler: helloworld.App::truckTracker
      Runtime: java11
      MemorySize: 512
```

Below is how I passed data into the method, using **events.json** and the **AWS console**.

```
{
  "lang":"102020203456151",
  "lon":"3000300303030"
}
```

Unfortunately I always end up with the following error.

```
{"errorMessage":"No public method named truckTracker with appropriate method signature found on class helloworld.App"}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: what package is App in?

Comment: @Stultuske: The package name in yaml is absolutely correct. I have executed couple of other methods successfully which involves passing pojo classes as parameters. All of them were in the same `App` class. I just removed them in the question.